# Разное оформление single.php(WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Этот код для **single.php** я взял из темы **twentyfifteen**

```js
<?php
/**
* The template for displaying all single posts and attachments
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Twenty_Fifteen
* @since Twenty Fifteen 1.0
*/

get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
<main id="main" class="site-main">

<?php
// Start the loop.
while ( have_posts() ) :
the_post();

/*
* Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want
* to use this in a child theme, then include a file called content-___.php
* (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
*/
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

// If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
comments_template();
endif;

// Previous/next post navigation.
the_post_navigation(
array(
'next_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">' . __( 'Next', 'twentyfifteen' ) . '</span> ' .
'<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next post:', 'twentyfifteen' ) . '</span> ' .
'<span class="post-title">%title</span>',
'prev_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">' . __( 'Previous', 'twentyfifteen' ) . '</span> ' .
'<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous post:', 'twentyfifteen' ) . '</span> ' .
'<span class="post-title">%title</span>',
)
);

// End the loop.
endwhile;
?>

</main><!-- .site-main -->
</div><!-- .content-area -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

А вот мой код для **single.php:**

```js
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php the_post(); ?>

<main class="Main_Content">

<article class="Text_Main_Block">

<h1 class ="first_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<br>
<?php the_content(); ?>

</article>
</main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Я не могу понять, почему код из оригинальной темы гораздо больше моего?
Чем код из темы **twentyfifteen** отличается от моего короткого кода?
**Ведь результат один и тот же.
Оба этих кода выводят текст и заголовок записи.**

Comment: Там же все расписано в комментариях. Где у вас подключение шаблона записи (может быть полезно), где комментарии, где навигация prev/next?

Comment: А что за prev/next? Что оно дает? И что за шаблон записей зачем он нужен?

Comment: @KAGGDesign ТС шарится по форумам и упорно не хочет учится.

Comment: Та я не шарюсь по форумам =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не одинаковый. Код из twentyfifteen может показывать комменты(если разрешены), показывать более одного поста(в зависимости от настроек), а также имеет навигацию(меню). У вас всего этого нет.